# Multiple aliases for a type T

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to create multiple aliases for a type, what I really need is like the below,

```
using MIN = MAX = AVG = nano_t;
```

(this seems more elegant, less typing, and also there is more than two cases where I have to do this kinda assignment), rather than doing this:

```
using....
using...
using... every time
```

but single line assignment doesn't make sense to the compiler as I want it to be.  Is there any-other way to do it?

Comment: Can you explain the use case for that requirement? What is the need behind the wish to have multiple aliases for a single type. And if you have MIN/MAX/AVG I would prefere something like MIN_T, MAX_T and so on. All that what you ask sounds a bit strange to me!

Answer (score 6):

`using` does not permit multiple aliases, but `typedef` does:

```
typedef nano_t MIN, MAX, AVG;
```

Comment: Thanks i should have think of that before but,in the code base  they already been `using` everywhere..yet your answer helps much in different place

Comment: @FallingFromBed `using` and `typedef` do much the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to do it in separate declarations:

```
using MIN = nano_t;
using MAX = nano_t;
using AVG = nano_t;
```

If you *really* want to follow [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (but I wouldn't bother in such a small example), you can do this:

```
using min_max_avg_aliased_type = nano_t;
using MIN = min_max_avg_aliased_type;
using MAX = min_max_avg_aliased_type;
using AVG = min_max_avg_aliased_type;
```

Comment: Single assignments isn't possible :(

Comment: @FallingFromBed Why? Can you elaborate (ideally by editing the question to include that explanation)?